# DataGridView issue - Calculated column value does not initially show up in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I am developing a Windows Forms application using C#, .Net 4.5, Entity Frameworks 6.1

I am using the following code to populate at DataGridView control.

```
var context = new MyVisionBidModelEntities();

bidItemMaterialBindingSource.DataSource = 
   context.BidItemMaterials.Where(c => c.BidItemID == selectedItem.BidItemID).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = bidItemMaterialBindingSource;
```

I then set compute the value of a "TotalPrice" column using the following code.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => !row.IsNewRow))
{
    CalculateTotalPrice(row);
}

private void CalculateTotalPrice(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    object a = row.Cells[1].Value;
    object b = row.Cells[2].Value;
    object c = row.Cells[3].Value;
    double aNumber = 0;
    double bNumber = 0;
    double cNumber = 0;
    if (a != null)
        aNumber = Double.Parse(a.ToString());
    if (b != null)
        bNumber = Double.Parse(b.ToString());
    if (c != null)
        cNumber = Double.Parse(c.ToString());
    row.Cells["TotalPrice"].Value = aNumber * bNumber * cNumber;
    row.Cells["TotalPrice"].ValueType = typeof(double);
}
```

When I initially view the DataGridView Control, All Rows and Columns are viewable, however, the TotalPrice Column has Null Values.

When I re-exectute the code above, the DataGridView now has the TotalPrice Values.

I have tried doing a DataGridView.Refresh, DataGridView.Update etc. But cannot make the Calculated Column show up initially.  It works fine on the second paint.

Am I missing Something?

Comment: You may need to calculate the total as part of the query for this to work as you want.

Comment: on the first paint, all rows are new rows... think about changing your foreach statement.

Comment: @JohnGnazzo I think that `MaxOvdriv` may as well tried to tell you what I'm gonna do, but since it's not getting clear I'll post a comment. When you execute this code `dataGridView1.DataSource = bidItemMaterialBindingSource;` before the `foreach` the `TotalPrice` column is null because you haven't gone through the foreach and setting values for it. First - make sure that all your columns have the correct data, and bind the datasource at the end.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

If your TotalPrice column is not bound I would make it a virtual column and do the calculation in the dataGrid's `CellValueNeeded` event, otherwise perform the calculation's before you set the DataGrid's DataSource property. There are still some more details you may have to workout depending on how your users will be using the grid, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

on the first paint, all rows are new rows... think about changing your foreach statement.

as requested by someone else, here's the code changed for you/work done for you:

Change this block:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => !row.IsNewRow))
{
    CalculateTotalPrice(row);
}
```

for this block instead:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    CalculateTotalPrice(row);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: hello, this is not a critique: i told him exactly what the problem was (on first paint, all rows are new rows), and then told him what to change (change your foreach statement)... if he does this, it will fix his problem.

Comment: You made a suggestion. This is not an answer!